# Webdriver manager causes UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u258e' in position 458: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I am new to Python, Selenium and automated testing. Working through a course, I encounter this error when Webdriver manager is required to update any browsers used (Chrome, Firefox or Edge):

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u258e' in position 458: character maps to <undefined>`

I'm using this bit of code in conftest.py:

```
def driver(request):

    browser = request.config.getoption("--browser")
    # browser = request.param
    print(f"Creating {browser} driver")
    if browser == "chrome":
        my_driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
    elif browser == "firefox":
        my_driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=FirefoxService(GeckoDriverManager().install()))
    elif browser == "edge":
        my_driver = webdriver.Edge(service=EdgeService(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install()))
    else:
        raise TypeError(f"Expected 'chrome', 'firefox' or 'edge', but got {browser}")
    # my_driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    yield my_driver
    print(f"Closing {browser} driver")
    my_driver.quit()
```

After the browser has been updated my tests function without this error.

Following some reading/research I think I understand the concept of this issue, and my suspicion is the problem occurs when WebDriver manager tries to display a message in the console? If so, do I need to force WebDriver manager to use UTF8 encoding somehow, or does the problem lay elsewhere, perhaps within my IDE?

I use PyCharm on Windows 11, and checking Settings>>Editor>>File Encodings I see the following:

[image: PyCharm Settings]

Changing settings to below and reloading my IDE makes no difference:

[image: UTF8EncodingSettingsInIDE]

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!